# Cannot install RuboCop on RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine, rubocop

I'm opening ruby file via RubyMine. IDE suggests installing RuboCop. I accept it, but after a few seconds it shows:

`Following gems were not installed: rubocop (1.0.0): Cancelled`

Documentation says its problem with interpreter path. Problem is its already set. Even when i try to add it like documentation says, it won't let me, because its already set.

Any ideas what i can do? I have been using VisualStudio Code without issues before it, but Ruby support is pretty poor, i had to use terminal, while for example python has full support and you can just run program with one button.

Comment: Anything interesting in the ide log? This looks like bug report to the RubyMine bugtracker.

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev i have no idea where ide log is. I will try to check it out.

Comment: For linux it's Help -> Show Log in Files